# VisualBasic errorscreen for letters

Tags: vb.net

I've got this calculator that I made for an assignement in programming for beginners at school, and the code is working fine, except for one thing
I can't seem to figure out how to make an errorscreen appear when letters are put in the my textbox instead of numbers..I've tried to put in a Try..Catch but all I get is crashes, could you please help me? :/  I'd really appreciate it
Thx

btw "atcie" 1 to 4 stand for +, - ,* and / 
and 'getal' means number :)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6vda.png)

Comment: When you're posting a question, it's much better to include the code as text. This way users can easily copy your exact code and modify/test it properly. Cheers - Have a look here about how to format your questions better - Thanks .. http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 1):

There is a function that returns 'True' if the contents of your textbox can be evaluated as a number. It's called 'IsNumeric'. You use it like this

```
If Actie_Selectie = True Then
    If IsNumeric(textBox.Text) Then
        getal2 = Val(textBox.Text) '
        'the rest of your code
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Numbers Only!")
    End If
  End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this event to your textbox to ignore the letters:

```
Private Sub mytextbox_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles mytextbox.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
        e.Handled = Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar)
    End If
End Sub
```